# Usage of PTR records aside from SMTP verification

Tags: dns

Usually, when I create a zone file, I create `PTR` records so that an SMTP server can perform a reverse DNS query and verify that a hostname matches the actual IP in the `A` record.

Since SMTP verification is the only real-world use of `PTR` records I'm aware of, I only create `PTR` records for hostnames which will be used to send email.

But are there any other uses of `PTR` records?  Should I create a `PTR` record for *every* `A` record in the zone file?  For example, if my zone file also has an `A` record for an HTTP server, (let's say www.example.com) - which will never be used to send email - is there any benefit to creating a `PTR` record for that as well?

Answer (score 0):

PTR records are useful in general when one has an IP address and wants to find what the address belongs to. The most common example might be various network status tools like `netstat`, where a user might see their computer connected to `superuser.com:https` versus `198.252.206.16:https`; or when examining firewall logs.

One very common, but irrelevant here, usage of reverse DNS is the IRC chat protocol. Due to its early BITNET and ARPANET influences, all users have their hostnames visible.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse DNS is also useful for traceroute and similar commands. I've only ever really gotten value out of that when doing it across the Internet to see which ISP is having a problem, but it can save you a bit of time in internal network troubleshooting too.